# DataGrid - key to run event handler on current item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The source to a small WPF program is shown below. It lists the directories under `c:\windows` in a `DataGrid`. The name is a link that can be clicked to open the directory in Explorer.

(This is just a proof of concept program to illustrate the question.)

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Instead of only being able to click on the link to run the open action, I'd also like to set it up so that the user can press the `o` key when a row is highlighted in order to run the open action.

What's a good way to set this up? Note that the program is primarily specified in C# as opposed to XAML so if possible, please post your solution in C#. However, if necessary, XAML answers are welcome too!

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfFilesDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfFilesDataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfFilesDataGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var data_grid = new DataGrid()
            {
                IsReadOnly = true,
                AutoGenerateColumns = false,
                ItemsSource = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\windows").GetDirectories()
            };

            {
                var setter = new EventSetter()
                {
                    Event = Hyperlink.ClickEvent,
                    Handler = (RoutedEventHandler)((sender, e) => 
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((data_grid.SelectedItem as DirectoryInfo).FullName);
                    })
                };

                var style = new Style();

                style.Setters.Add(setter);

                var col = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn()
                {
                    Header = "FullName",
                    Binding = new Binding("FullName"),
                    ElementStyle = style
                };

                data_grid.Columns.Add(col);
            }

            data_grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = "CreationTime",
                Binding = new Binding("CreationTime")
            });

            var dock_panel = new DockPanel();

            dock_panel.Children.Add(data_grid);

            Content = dock_panel;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
data_grid.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    if(e.Key == Key.O && data_grid.SelectedItem is DirectoryInfo di)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(di.FullName);
};
```

Comment: Works perfectly and so simple! Thanks @mm8!

Comment: [Separate but related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624087/previewkeydown-with-system-diagnostics-process-startsome-url-opens-two-browser) in case you happen to know :-) :