# PreviewKeyDown with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(some url) opens two browsers

Tags: c#, wpf, process.start

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616200/datagrid-key-to-run-event-handler-on-current-item) (and accepted answer) a simple WPF program sets up a `PreviewKeyDown` handler to call `Process.Start` on a directory name to open that folder in Windows File Explorer.

If I change the handler definition to open up a URL as follows:

```
data_grid.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Key == Key.O && data_grid.SelectedItem is DirectoryInfo info)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.github.com");
};
```

it opens up two browser tabs when I press the `o` key.

The original version did not open two *File Explorer* windows.

Why does the URL version open two browser windows? What's a good way to get it to only open one?

To make this concrete and more explicit, here's an entire program which demonstrates the issue.

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUrlsDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfUrlsDataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfUrlsDataGrid
{
    public class Address { public string Url { get; set; } }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var data_grid = new DataGrid()
            {
                IsReadOnly = true,
                AutoGenerateColumns = true,
                ItemsSource = new[] 
                {
                    new Address() { Url = "https://www.google.com" },
                    new Address() { Url = "https://www.github.com" },
                    new Address() { Url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com" }
                }
            };

            data_grid.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.O && data_grid.SelectedItem is Address address)
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(address.Url);
            };

            var dock_panel = new DockPanel();

            dock_panel.Children.Add(data_grid);

            Content = dock_panel;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the example program looks like:

[image]

---

**UPDATE** in response to comments below

If I add a breakpoint at the following line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(address.Url);
```

Only one browser tab opens! Very strange that the behaviour is different when debugging.

---

**UPDATE** in response to comments below

If I change the browser that is used to Microsoft Edge as follows:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String.Format("microsoft-edge:{0}", address.Url));
```

it still opens up two tabs.

---

**UPDATE**

The issue seems to be intermittent. **Most** of the time, it opens two browser tabs. However, occasionally it will open only one tab.

Comment: Use the debugger and see if your function is called twice by setting a breakpoint there

Comment: Also check if this changes when you change your standard browser to a different browser just to make sure its not the browser trying to open a start-page or something like that

Comment: Hi @DenisSchaf! Thanks for taking a look. I've added some updates to the question in response to your comments.

Comment: try using the `KeyDown` event  instead of `PreviewKeyDown`

Comment: I tested and it works for me . it opens only one window. Is it something wrong with keyboard ? May be sending many 2 keystrokes instead of 1? Try using some other key instead of o maybe? i once had this problem with printscreen key. Just one keypress sent 5 keystrokes. So try to change the keyboard?

Comment: @nath The issue occurs both with the external keyboard as well as the laptop keyboard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211503/17034

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reference. It looks like in your answer there, you're using a `BeginInvoke` that's part of Windows Forms. The demo app above is in WPF. Is there a good an equivalent of `BeginInvoke` for WPF?

Answer (score 1):

```
data_grid.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Key == Key.O && data_grid.SelectedItem is DirectoryInfo info)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.github.com");
    **e.Handled = true;**
};
```

Comment: Hmm... So, with this approach, it does seem to eliminate the double browser tab issue! However, the 'up' and 'down' arrow keys no longer change the current selected row.

Comment: A slight modification of this approach seems to work! I've added an answer based on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems to resolve the issue:

```
data_grid.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => 
{
    if (e.Key == Key.O && data_grid.SelectedItem is Link link)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((data_grid.SelectedItem as Link).Url);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
};
```

Note that it's a *slight* modification of the answer by @user11344985. It moves the `e.Handled = true;` line into the if body.